# Laravel - dd() model with all relationships

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to die & dump the Model and see all relationships with dd() or var_dump()?

So i can see everything what is connected to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load model with relation, for example:

```
$collection = Model::with('relation', 'nested.relation')->get();
```

When you'll do `dd($collection);` you'll see all relation models there.

Comment: hmm can i call this with my $model variable....somehow?? Something like $event->with....

Comment: @lewis4u `$model->load('relation')`

Comment: yeess... it works....and what about nested relations,,,,,how to get those

Comment: @lewis4u I've shown how to load nested relations in my answer. For example, if `user` has `articles` and `articles` have `comments`, you can load `comments` with `'articles.comments'`

Comment: oh...just to append a "." dot to it..ok i get it